# How to get a list of the arguments a method is called with

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How do I get a list of the arguments passed to a method, preferably one that I can iterate through?

For example something like

```
def foo(a,b,c)
  puts args.inspect
end

foo(1,2,3)
=> [1,2,3]
```

?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always define a method that takes an arbitrary number of arguments:

```
def foo(*args)
  puts args.inspect
end
```

This does exactly what you want, but only works on methods defined in such a manner.

The `*args` notation means "zero or more arguments" in this context. The opposite of this is the splat operator which expands them back into a list, useful for calling other methods.

As a note, the `*`-optional arguments must come last in the list of arguments.

Comment: Hmmm, and unfortunately doesn't work with named arguments (so 'a' will not be created on instantiation).  Good answer though

Comment: @juwiley: See my answer for something that's vaguely similar to named arguments.

Answer (score 3):

If you define your method as you specified, you'll always have 3 args, or the method call is invalid. So "all the args" is already defined for you. So you would just change your method to:

```
def foo(a,b,c)
  [a, b, c]
end
```

To define a method that can be called with any args (and to then access those args) you can do something like this:

```
def foo(*args)
  args
end
```

What the `*` does is put all args after that point into an array.

Comment: Hey Emily, the usecase I'm thinking of is looping through the arguments I get to the method, and raising an error if any of them is nil or not of a particular class.  I'd like to do that in a one liner instead of says "raise if a.nil? || !a.kind_of?(Integer)"

Comment: Well, I don't know of any way to directly get all the arguments, but you can at least simplify the conditional to do something like `raise ArgumentError if [a,b,c].any?{ |arg| arg.nil? or arg.kind_of? Integer }`

Comment: Yes, I ended up with something like that

Answer (score 2):

As others pointed out you can use the splat operator (`*`) for achieving what you want. If you don't like that, you can use the fact that Ruby methods can take a hash as last argument with nicer syntax.

```
def foo(args)
  raise ArgumentError if args.keys.any? { |arg| arg.nil? || !arg.kind_of?(Integer) }
end

puts foo(:a => 1, :b => 2, :c => "a") # raise an ArgumentError
```

To access the arguments inside the method you have to use `args[:a]` etc.